# Cheapest from Europe to Canada

Tags: air-travel, tickets, canada

what time of year are the cheapest flights from Europe (the Netherlands)? I don't care about weather or holidays.

Comment: Thanks. Did you have to select specific dates or could you just use the graph to see when it's cheapest?

Comment: try google. they have graphs.

Answer (score 1):

I used google flights to book mine from Canada -> Europe. It fetches all flights from multiple airline companies and even offers graphs showing prices according to departure & return dates.

Here's an example link to get you there: https://www.google.com/flights/flights-from-paris-to-montreal.html

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Flight prices vary a lot with many different factors. In general "no vacation" & "bad weather" and "no special events" drive prices down but there are lots and lots of exceptions and local variations.

There are search engines that helps with this, e.g. http://matrix.itasoftware.com/ or www.adioso.com

For example, in November the cheapest from AMS seems to be Amsterdam<->Toronto for $367 US dollars (317 Euro) on WOW air. Air Canada has similar pricing for some dates.